# The start of an edge when this start is a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, edge

The description of the edge operation

```
\path ... edge[<options>] <nodes> (<coordinate>) ...
```

opens with the following explanation (p. 246, chapter 17 'Nodes and Edges' in the TikZ part of the manual):

> The effect of the `edge` operation is that after the main path the following path is added to the picture:
>
> `\path[every edge, 〈options〉] (\tikztostart)〈path〉;`
>
> Here, `〈path〉` is the `to path` . Note that, unlike the path added by the `to` operation, the `(\tikztostart)` is added before the `〈path〉` (which is unnecessary for the `to` operation, since this coordinate is already part of the main path).
>
> The `\tikztostart` is the last coordinate on the path just before the `edge` operation, just as for the `node` or `to` operations. However, there is one exception to this rule: If the `edge` operation is directly preceded by a `node` operation, then this just-declared node is the start coordinate (and not, as would normally be the case, the coordinate where this just-declared node is placed – a small, but subtle difference). In this regard, `edge` differs from both `node` and `to`.

I don't understand the "small, but subtle difference" mentioned in the last paragraph. How can a *node* be the *coordinate* of anything? A node is a node, and a coordinate is a coordinate, except when a node has the `coordinate` shape, but I don't think this is what is meant here. And if we interpret this occurrence of the word "node" as "the coordinate where the node is anchored", then what is the difference between this coordinate and "the coordinate where this just-declared node is placed"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinate where the node is placed is, by default, the `center` and this is the coordinate the path is constructed to and from. When an edge is used, the relevant border anchor is used as the coordinate.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path [draw] (0,0) -- ++(1,1) node [draw] {node on path} -- ++(1,1);
  \path [draw] (0,-2) ++(1,1) node [draw] {node before edge} edge ++(1,1) edge ++(-1,-1)  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: placements vs. border anchors]